I cant find the button in HTML for selenium
I am making a selenium script to automate some browser activity using tor browser, which doesnt save cookies, so everytime the script opens the website, this pop up is there and i need the script to press "accept all" so i can log in after, but in the HTML code, there is no button and just a bunch of div contaienrs.
I tried using driver.find_element_by_css_selector, classname and xpath, i tried adding a delay so i am sure the page is loaded properly and i hoped it would work to click on the button, but it cant find the button since i think i am just finding the div container and no button.enter image description here

Please post the HTML as text, not screenshot.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The element you are trying to access is inside a shadow root element. You can't access it directly.
If you are using selenium 4, then you can use the following code to access the element.
shadow_root_element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.cmp-root-container')
accept_button = shadow_root_element.shadow_root.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.cmp-button-accept-all')
accept_button.click()

Or you can get the shadow root by executing script and then access the inner element.
shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector("div.cmp-root-container").shadowRoot')
accept_button = shadow_root.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.cmp-button-accept-all')
accept_button.click()

